# Georgia/Tbilisi restaurant etiquette

Tags: food-and-drink, georgia-country

In Georgia, as a solo diner, if you have leftover half a bottle of wine or whatever with a meal in a restaurant, is it acceptable to take the half-full bottle with you when you leave?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem in asking for the remainder of the wine bottle, nor in asking for "doggy bags" for leftover food.

As well as the cost advantage (the cost of a whole bottle is only about 2.3-2.5x that of a glass) there is a far greater selection when ordered by the bottle.

Typical wine list at a relatively fancy restaurant (**much** cheaper drinkable wines are available at supermarkets etc.):

[image]